# Maximal subgroup, prime index

Tags: group-theory

How can I show that if the index of a subgroup is prime, then the subgroup is maximal?

Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*  $H \subseteq K \subseteq G \implies (G:H) = (G:K)\,(K:H)$.